# Why my cursor can not delete the word in the correct place?

Tags: firefox, browser, latex, sharelatex

When I delete and write words in ShareLaTeX, the action does not occur in the right place. For example,[image] 
you can see the cursor is in line 4, when I click backspace to delete, it didn't delete the letter nearby, here is the result
[image]
As you can see, it deleted the letter "e". What is the problem?

Comment: Try using a different browser and see whether the problem persists.

Comment: @Werner Unfortunately the problem still exists in google-chrome(before this I used firefox and found the problem). It is really strange because I searched online then found nothing similar to this. Sorry for replying to you so late!

Comment: I used it in centos7 system. And I am a Chinese, so I choose the Chinese language as my system language. Is this relevant?

Comment: It could be relevant. Turn off all extensions in the browser, since that might affect the display as well.